# How to transfer an image obtained from a windows phone to a c# picturebox image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone app that takes a picture and sends it to a wcf service which sends it to a database so another app (windows forms app) can check the database and obtain the image.

It's adding data to the database as a byte array but when I check the values, they all say the same numbers, but it seems it works because theirs data there.

When I try to turn that data into an image though, it throws an exception saying the parameter isn't valid. I've searched for how to do this but what i find (even on here) says exactly what I'm doing. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

here's my code for the windows phone:

```
if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            var bitImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitImage.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            //image is a Image Control in the form
            ImageServiceClient client = new ImageServiceClient();

            byte[] array;
            using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(bitImage.PixelWidth, bitImage.PixelHeight);

                // write an image into the stream
                btmMap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitImage.PixelWidth, bitImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                array = stream.ToArray();
            }
            client.AddImageAsync(array);
        }
```

the last line calls the add method in my wcf service  which looks like:

```
public void AddImage(byte[] array)
    {
        var con =
            new MySqlConnection(
                "server=instance11297.db.xeround.com;User Id=Admin;Password=nomoredrama2010;port=7692;database=capstone");
       con.Open();
        string h = array.Aggregate(h, (current, b) => current + b);
        string text = "INSERT INTO images VALUES (''," + h + ")";
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        var command = new MySqlCommand(text, con);
        var result = command.ExecuteReader();
       result.Close();
    }
```

It's good to note that it doesn't matter if I use the passed in array directly or  if I turn it into text, they both show up the same in the database.

Then finally, in the app this is sending everything to, I have this:

```
var con =
            new MySqlConnection(
                "server=instance11297.db.xeround.com;User Id=Admin;Password=nomoredrama2010;port=7692;database=capstone");
        con.Open();
        string h = "";
        string text = "select Image from images where ImageId=4";
        var command = new MySqlCommand(text, con);
        var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        var g = new byte[] {};
        if(dr.Read())
          g = (byte[])dr[0];
        dr.Close();
        var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(g));
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

but it always breaks on "var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(g));" saying the parameter is not valid.

I found out it has a big array once it gets the image but the one in the database is only 65 bytes and they all say 57.

Why is it completely disregarding my image's array and replacing it with a 65 byte one of all 57?

What am I doing wrong?

************************EDIT****************************************************

I finally found what was wrong after enabling debugger in a wcf app. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx (for those who don't know)

I also looked here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9686/Save-An-Image-Into-SQL-Server-2000-Database

to see why it was throwing a "your sql is wrong" type error and changed my sql statement to use the adding method instead of putting the value into the string.

That fixed it finally. The working code looks like this for nayone else comes across this problem:

```
public void AddImage(byte[] array)
    {
        var con =
            new MySqlConnection("server=instance11297.db.xeround.com;User Id=Admin;Password=nomoredrama2010;port=7692;database=capstone");
        con.Open();
        string text = "INSERT INTO images (ImageId, Image) VALUES ('',@bytes)";
        var command = new MySqlCommand(text, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bytes", array);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

I can finally stop beating my head against the wall. :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use something like this.

//---read the data in buffer and write to ms2---

MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();

ms2.Write(b, 0, b.Lenght);

//---load it in a PictureBox control---

pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(ms2);